# Determine whether a circle is inside a "polygon" defined by vertices

Tags: matlab

I have a circle (`imellipse`) that I know the coordinates of the center, its radius, and several of its vertices. I need to find out whether this circle is inside or outside of a "polygon" defined by 360 points. I wanted to implement the solution described in: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7735/how-do-i-test-if-a-circle-and-concave-polygon-intersect, but I do not know how I would test for intersection between a ray from one vertex of the circle and the "polygon" defined by 360 points.

Edit: I am currently attempting to create 360 piecewise defined functions that determine the "edges" of the "polygon" and test for intersection between a vertical ray from the top of the circle to these 360 "edges."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it or not, there is a built in function [inpolygon](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html). That should handle this for you quite easily.